# How to set the ticks of log scale for x&y axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a log scale graph without scientific notation.

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.plot(np.arange(0,10,0.1))

    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xlim(0.1,100)
    plt.ylim(1,10)

    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    plt.show()
```

Question:

1. Y axis still shows the format of scientific notation. How to change it?
2. How to make specific ticks for y axis? I tried `plt.yticks([1,10])`, but it doesn't work.
3. How to get rid of the decimal point of ticks for both x and y axis?

   [image]

Answer (score 3):

**1. Get rid of Scientific notation.**

The ticks are major and minor ticks, hence you would need to set the minor formatter as well:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

**2. Show ticks at specific custom locations**

Getting rid of the minor ticklabels allows `yticks` to work as expected.

```
plt.yticks([1,10])
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.NullFormatter())
```

**3. Getting rid of the decimal points**

I suppose it does not make sense to get rid of the decimal points for a label like `0.1`. Hence one would probably choose a `StrMethodFormatter` with the **g**eneral purpose numeric format `g`.

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter("{x:g}"))
```

Comment: Thanks. What does `"{x:g}"` do? I also tried `plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())`, but the two end points `y=10^0` and `y=10^1` don't change.

Comment: `g` is the general format which only shows as many decimal places as needed. The two endpoints are major ticks, for those you need the major formatter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')` to get rid of the scientific notation.
2. It looks like `plt.yticks([1,10])` did its job. `yticks()` only adds the specific numbers you provide, not a range. So the ticks that it added were at y=1 and y=10, which are exactly at the bottom and top edges of your graph. If you want to have more ticks between those, you can try `plt.yticks(np.arange(1,10, step=d))` where 'd' is the distance you want between each step.
3. Try `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.EngFormatter(places=0))` to get rid of the decimal points.

All this can be found in the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html) docs, though admittedly it takes some digging.

Comment: Thanks. It shows `This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.` when I try to use `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`. It shows `100 m` in the first tick's position when I try to use `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.EngFormatter(places=0))`